# No success with retrieving POST Data from AJAX Call to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve data from ajax call. I get data from a html select tag without any submit button that created by php code and then i want to pass them to an ajax call and use them in a php code at the same file.

I tried this code but no success:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
        $selected_option = $_POST['value'];
        echo $selected_option;
        exit;
    }
    ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#percents').change(pass_the_value());
    });

    function pass_the_value() {
        var selected = $('#percents').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                value: selected
            },
            success: function() {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div>
        <select name='percents' id='percents' onchange='pass_the_value()'>
            <option value="0.1" selected="selected">10%</option>
            <?php

            // A sample array
            $products = array(
                "0.2" => "20%",
                "0.3" => "30%",
                "0.4" => "40%",
                "0.5" => "50%",
                "0.6" => "60%",
                "0.7" => "70%"
            );

            foreach ($products as $key => $item) {

                echo "<option value='{$key}'>$item</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is what i get in console log

```
(index):20 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.success
```

and this as php error:

```
Undefined index: value in C:\xampp7\htdocs\test\index.php on line 3
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Are you seeing any error in your browser console ? Is ajax call is successful?

Comment: Where is your url?

Comment: Please clarify what **exactly** is not working. Most of the time, this is either an AJAX problem (such that the request is not sent properly), or a PHP problem (such that the request is not handled properly), but rarely a problem of both technologies

Comment: @Swati I get this in console `(index):20 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.success`  and this `Undefined index: value in C:\xampp7\htdocs\test\index.php on line 3` as php error

Comment: @Dorvalla The php code and script are in the same file. I don't want pass data to another php file.

Comment: Hi here `success: function() {` you need to pass `data` as parameter i.e : `success: function(data) {`

Comment: @Swati Thanks! I don't have any console log error anymore, but I still have that php error.

Comment: Are you sure if `var selected = $('#percents').val();` giving you correct value ? put `alert(selected)` see what is giving .

Comment: @Swati Yes it gives correct value. Every Time I select dropdown value it changes and shows correct value.

Comment: That error should not come..according to me because `value` is under `if(isset($_POST['value'])) {..` not sure where might be problem .

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the URL you would like to call in `$.ajax`.

Add this line to your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{yourURL}',
    type: 'POST',
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a URL for the POST request. Look into the parameters here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: I don't want pass that data to another php file, script and php code are in the same php file. I mean something like dropdown.php that includes scripts and php codes.